# How to optimize Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have Social engine, and they user Zend Framework...i looking for some way to make it faster.

1) folder with Zend FrameWork 20mb...
What do you think about deleting all comments from php code ? Can make work faster?

Comment: use soft link / symbolic link

Comment: for what? php is server-side. I it will be about 0.00001 seconds faster after it.

Answer (score 2):

- Don't guess what is slow. You seem to think that because it is large it means that is the slow bit. Maybe you only use 500k of that 20mb. Use a profiler and find what is actually slow.
- You should be using some sort of cache, something like APC.
- Comments are probably a fairly trivial part of execution time, negligible with an opcode cache.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting comments won't make any PHP application run any faster (noticeably, anyway).

Optimizing is also quite a broad term, do you want to make it have a smaller memory footprint? Smaller in physical disk space it takes up? Faster execution time?

You should look at the App itself and try to find the bottleneck - are you using Caching where possible? Are databases indexed etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great article about speeding up web site

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html